# add config value to VSCode snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I created a project for a VSCode extension.
I added a configuration value to the package.json file:

```
"contributes": {
     "commands": [{
       "command": "MyProject.UpdateValue",
       "title": "Contains my configuration value"
     }]
}
```

This part works fine. If from code I ask it to return the value of `MyProject.UpdateValue` it does it correctly.

I would like the same value returned to me within a snippet.

```
{
  "Print to console": {
    "prefix": "PrintToConsole",
    "body": ["console.log('{1:MyProject.UpdateValue}')"],
    "description": "Insert Console log with config"
  }
}
```

when I use this snippet it gives me:
console.log('MyProject.UpdateValue')
instead I would like it returned
console.log('ConfigValue')

Comment: where in the snippet doc page is a mentioning that you can call a command from a snippet.

Comment: with the extension [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates) v1.13 you can create a snippet/template that can call a command